# Problems with position:absolute on element when printing - IE8

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8, position, stylesheet

I have run into a problem with absolute positioning on elements in IE8 when printing.
I have my print stylesheet, and in this I'm trying to position an element in the top right corner of the first printed page.

The problem is that when the element is placed on page two, IE8 thinks that the top of the page in on page two, instead of page one.

This is in my print.css:

```
.myElem{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:230px;
}
```

In all other browsers (Opera 11, Firefox 3.6, Safari 5, Chrome 11, IE9, IE9 compatibility mode, IE8 compatibility mode) the .myElem-div will be printed on the first page in the top right corner. But in IE8 the div is printed in the top right corner of the second page. As said before the div is located "on the second print page" in the DOM. I can't move the element up earlier in my DOM, so this is not a solution.

Actually it's the same problem as descibed in the comments by other users here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CommunityContent

Anyone have a solution to this?

Thank you very muvh in advance!

Regards,
Kim

Comment: try removing the doc type tag of page.

Comment: Hehe, that might work, but this will mess up all of my styling on the page. Unless it's posible to only remove the doc type on the printed version, this is unfortunately not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible workarounds... not really fixes.

1. Create printer-friendly versions of the pages that do not require a `doctype`, which is probably causing IE8 to choke.  Of course, this is a lot of work... unless you do not have too many pages or you can generate those pages dynamically using server side tech.
2. Create an IE8-only stylesheet using conditional comments, example `<!-- [if IE 8]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-8.0.css" /> <![endif]-->` and use this sheet to remove that `div` altogether with a `display:none;`, assuming that you could do without it.

Comment: Sorry Jason. This can not be my solution either. I need the element on the page, and a version without a doc type unfortunately can't be made.